# How to check if folder has any content in puppet

Tags: puppet, cp

What I want to do is check whether a folder has any content before copying the content in the folder, since puppet is throwing an error if you are trying to copy content of a empty folder. This is what I have tried but it doesn't work :(

```
exec { "Copying_patches_$setupnode-$number":

      path    => '/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/opt/java/bin/', 
      command => "cp -r ${params::script_base_dir}/libs/patches/* ${params::deployment_target}/$setup/repository/patches/",
      onlyif => "test -f ${params::script_base_dir}/libs/patches/*",
      notify          => Notify['${params::script_base_dir}/libs/patches/*  found'],
      require => File["${params::deployment_target}/$setupnode"],

    }
```

params::script_base_dir will give the path up to the script location.

Comment: Are you averse to using `rsync` instead of `cp`? That would make this job trivial (`rsync` can be told to copy a whole folder **or** all contents of a folder, without complaint if there are none).

Comment: Is rsync natively supported on any linux distribution?

Comment: It is not part of coreutils, if that's what you're asking. It usually resides in its own package. Puppet will happily install that for you, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this approach:

```
package { 'rsync': ensure => 'installed' }

$from = "${params::script_base_dir}/libs/patches/"
$to   = "${params::deployment_target}/$setup/repository/patches/"

file { "$from/.sync_marker": ensure => file }

exec { "Copying_patches_$setupnode-$number":
  path    => '/usr/bin:/bin', 
  command => "rsync -r $from $to",
  require => [
    File["${params::deployment_target}/$setupnode"],
    Package['rsync'],
    File["$from/.sync_marker"],
  ],
  creates => "$to/.sync_marker",
}
```

Some remarks:

1. I shortened your `path` - no need for java or things in `/sbin`
2. Notifying a `notify` resource is usually no sensible - those always produce their message
3. The trailing slash on the target does not matter to `rsync`, but the one on the sources does!
4. The file in the source directory is created, just to make it possible to build a simple `creates` clause

The `creates` parameter makes sure that the command is run only once, and not during every run.

If you need Puppet to wait until the source directory is populated, you do have to use `onlyif`. Try this condition:

```
onlyif => "find $from | wc -l | grep -v '^2\$'",
```

The two lines of output would represent the directory itself and the marker file. The `$` sign is escaped so that Puppet includes it in the command string literally.

Comment: The exec condition could be simplified testing for empty directory, e.g. `onlyif => 'test -z "$(ls -A /target/dir)"'`

Answer (score 0):

spent a little bit of time to find it, This might help someone else as well

```
unless  => "find /directory/path/ -mindepth 1 | read",
```

So wanted

```
  exec { "Install wordpress in ${docroot}":
    command => "git clone https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress.git ${docroot}",
    unless  => "find ${docroot} -mindepth 1 | read", # only cloen if directory is empty
    cwd     => $docroot,
    path    => ['/bin', '/usr/bin', '/usr/sbin'],
  }
```